# Search Keyword and Code from one search

Tags: php, html, search, keyword

Currently I have 2 search boxes, one for keywords and one for product codes.

I would like to only have 1 search box but allow users to search both keywords and codes. \

My search.php file currently contains :

```
if(isset($counter)){
    for($r=1;$r<$counter;$r++){
        $division_breadcrumb .= $filters[$r]["div"].$filters[$r]["cats"].'<p class="clear"></p>';
        mysql_free_result($query2);
        unset($_GET['division2'],$data2);
    }
}


//Code or keyword is used   
} elseif (isset($_POST['keyword']) || isset($_POST['code'])){
    $keyword = NULL;
    if(isset($_POST['keyword'])){
        if($_POST['keyword'] != 'keyword' && $_POST['keyword'] != ''){
            if(strpos($_POST['keyword'],' ')!==false){
                $_POST['keyword'] = str_replace(' ', ' +',$_POST['keyword']);
                if((strpos($_POST['keyword'],'s ')!==false) && (strpos($_POST['keyword'],'ss ')===false)) $_POST['keyword'] = str_replace('s ', ' ',$_POST['keyword']);
                if(substr($_POST['keyword'],strlen($_POST['keyword'])-1)=='s') $_POST['keyword'] = substr($_POST['keyword'],0,(strlen($_POST['keyword'])-1));

                $keyword = 'AND MATCH (WEB_InventTable.ItemName,WEB_InventTable.Range,WEB_InventTable.Description) AGAINST ("+'.$_POST['keyword'].'" IN BOOLEAN MODE)';
            }else{
                if(substr($_POST['keyword'],strlen($_POST['keyword'])-1)=='s') $_POST['keyword'] = substr($_POST['keyword'],0,(strlen($_POST['keyword'])-1));
                $keyword = 'AND (ItemName LIKE "% '.$_POST['keyword'].' %" OR ItemName LIKE "'.$_POST['keyword'].' %" OR ItemName LIKE " %'.$_POST['keyword'].'") ';
            }
        }

        if($_POST['keyword'] == 'keyword'){
            $_POST['keyword'] = NULL;
        }
    }

    $code = NULL;
    if(isset($_POST['code'])){
        if($_POST['code'] != 'code' && $_POST['code'] != '' && $_POST['code'] != 'code'){
            $code = 'AND ItemId LIKE "%'.$_POST['code'].'%"';
        }
        if($_POST['code'] == 'code'){
            $_POST['code'] = NULL;
        }
    }

    $link = 'page=Search&amp;keyword='.$_POST['keyword'].'&amp;code='.$_POST['code'];
```

Comment: `} elseif (isset($_POST['keyword']) || isset($_POST['code'])){` where is the corresponding `if` block for this ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, When posting it seems as though it cut off. Please see above

Comment: You can't have these statements `mysql_free_result($query2);unset($_GET['division2'],$data2);` inbetween. Either they should go inside of the `if` or the `elseif` block.

Comment: Thanks @ShankarDamodaran, I have updated to include in the `if` statement

Comment: That would depend on how is your product code and keywords are distinguished . If you have a way to know weather you have entered the keyword or product code then you can simply add the condition otherwise I dont see any way except to have another dropdown to select the type of search.